# Headers and caching in REST service call from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, caching, rest

I've been developing a small Silverlight client, which will talk to a REST service build using the WCF WEBAPI....
When the service is called using GET, it'll kick of a long running process, that'll generate a resource, so the service will return 'Accepted' and a URI in a Location header, to where the resource will be found.

```
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date:   Fri, 18 Nov 2011 09:00:17 GMT
X-AspNet-Version:   4.0.30319
Content-Length: 3
Location:   http://localhost:52878/myservice?fileid=f68201f6-9d77-4818-820e-e5e796e9710a
Cache-Control   public, max-age=21600
Expires:    21600
Content-Type:   text/plain
Connection: Close
```

Now, in my Silverlight client, I need to access this header information, however using the BrowserHTTP stack, this is not possible... so I've switched to the ClientHTTP, which makes it possible for me to access the header information returned.
However the ClientHTTP stack doesn't support Content Caching:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/10/14/silverlight-3-s-new-client-networking-stack.aspx

which is causing me troubles..... I wan't the same resource to be returned for 6 hours, before a new one is generated.

Is there a way to get the best of both... being able to access the Header info AND have content caching??

TIA

Søren

Answer (score 0):

Stop using a header to return the information needed by the client code.

If you include the required information in the entity body using either raw or encoded in some message format (e.g. XML or JSON) then you can continue to use the BrowserHTTP and benefit from its caching.

Comment: I've joined a class with Ian Robinson, and he advocated for using the header for this... according to him it was to proper way of doing it.... so I'd rather not put it in the body...

Comment: @smolesen: I submit that the "proper way of doing it" is one that a) works and b) is the simplest.  Others may have other reasons why they do things differently but do those reasons match with things that __you__ actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Using the headers is the correct way to convey this information. That's why it's in the standard. 
I don't do silverlight, but what I get from that post is that you will now need to implement the caching. Using the BrowserHttp leverages the browsers caching mechanism. Now using ClientHttp you are dropping closer to the metal and you will have to implement caching.

Comment: Correct: Following existing standards that define solutions to complex problems instead of coming up with new solutions. Today's quick solutions are tomorrows problems. By adding an additional way to convey caching you might add ambiguity for future developers. Just use what exists. The entire web uses the header and the caching control defined in it which is simple and that seemed to work